# convert hashed string value into SHA256

Tags: c#, hash, sha256

From the server, I am getting already hashed string value.
 
What I need to do on a client side is to convert that hashed value into primary SHA256 and then(from another method) get from this SHA256 an original human-readable string.
 
Can anybody share the code for that solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHA256 is a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm.  Therefore, you cannot de-crypt a hash value to get the original value.

Here's a link from our friends at the Information Security Stack Exchange:

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/145287

Comment: that is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks!